# How to get handler(HWND) for dialog box

Tags: c++, mfc

Hi I have created a dialog box and it woks.

My question is: how do you retreive the handle for it?

Also, if you get the handle, how would you change the static text control text inside it?

```
class CStatisticsDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CStatisticsDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_STATISTICS };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
};

CStatisticsDlg::CStatisticsDlg() : CDialogEx(CStatisticsDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CStatisticsDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CStatisticsDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: Post your code. Even though the question is simple, there is no mind reading to understand what you are trying to do. Where exactly you need the handle in particular.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're using MFC (as indicated by the tag), then presumably you have a [`CDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/132s802t.aspx) class instance.  `CDialog` is a subclass of [`CWnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xb05f0h.aspx), so you can retrieve the window handle by one of 3 ways:

- Directly accessing its [`m_hWnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwdbkfhc.aspx) member
- Casting it to an `HWND` with [`operator HWND()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcs64shx.aspx)
- Calling [`GetSafeHwnd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d64ehwhz.aspx) on it

Comment: thx for the reply. A related question....assuming you have the handle for the dialog box....and you have static text control in it....how do you change the text in the control at runtime....i have tried SetDlgItemText but this does not seem to be having any effect.

Comment: In the resource editor make sure your give your static text a unique ID. Then I suggest you map the control to a CStatic variable or a CString. Either way you will be able to update the variable content. Please keep in mind that by default of static labels have the same ID IDC_STATIC so you have to give them unique ID values if you want to edit their values at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it.
First create a member function to the main application class.
Then use the following code (Assuming the class name is **CGenericApp**, and your Dialog class is **CGenericDlg**.

```
CWnd* CGenericApp::GetDlg()
{
    return m_pMainWnd;
}
```

Then when you want to get a handler to the main Dialog box, use:

```
CGenericApp* app = (CGenericApp*)AfxGetApp();
CGenericDlg* pDlg = (CGenericDlg*)(app->GetDlg());
HWND win = pDlg->GetSafeHwnd();
```

'win' will hold the HWND you are looking for.